# The "Copy" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, msbuildcommunitytasks

Team,

I am trying to migrate a .NET framework 2.0 targetting solution to .NET 4.0 . I am facing a problem while i am doing a build.

The error is as such

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2869,13): error MSB4064: The "SourceFiles" parameter is not supported by the "Copy" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2868,9): error MSB4063: The "Copy" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

May i know how to get around this type of MSbuild issues? I know my converted solution should target the .NET framework 4.0 build. But how do we do it? Tried several ways editing the Microsoft.Common.Targets file but with no success. Please can anyone help me

Comment: Did you add ToolsVersion="4.0" to all your project files, and are you running from a command line with the correct environment?

Comment: Yes, stijn. I have already done that. in fact i am using the VS 2010 to do the conversion and it has successfullly converted the project files with the toolversion as 4.0.

Comment: to add to the comment above i am using the VS 2010 to do the build.even if i do the msbuild from the command line prompt it gives me the same error

Comment: you could try to create a new empty project, add a couple of your source files and see if that builds. If so, compare the new vs the converted project files to figure out the difference?

Comment: Hi stjin...i think i found out from where the error is emanating. I used the diagnostic logging of the msbuild process and here are the details

Answer (score -1):

I think I found out from where the error is emanating. I used the diagnostic logging of the msbuild process and here are the details

Using "Copy" task from assembly

```
"D:\RR_VS_2010\Trunk\Hindsite\Source\MicrosoftSDCTasks\..\..\Library\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.dll".
Task "Copy" (TaskId:20)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3002,13): error MSB4064: The "SourceFiles" parameter is not supported by the "Copy" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. [D:\RR_VS_2010\Trunk\Hindsite\Source\Edenbrook\Hindsite\DAL\Edenbrook.hindsite.dal.csproj]
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3001,9): error MSB4063: The "Copy" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  [D:\RR_VS_2010\Trunk\Hindsite\Source\Edenbrook\Hindsite\DAL\Edenbrook.hindsite.dal.csproj]
Done executing task "Copy" -- FAILED. (TaskId:20)
```

Please let me know if this is anything to do with the dll.. Do i have to use the updated dll for .NET 4.0 framework.